# In webdriver, how to verify dropdown field is displayed or not using Java

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I need to verify whether the dropdown field is displayed in the screen or not using Java in webdriver. This dropdown field will display in this a screen after selecting the checkbox in another screen only.I have used the following code to verify the field is displayed or not but, it is not returning any value like true or false.

```
driver.findElements(By.name("ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$DdlPwdExp"));
driver.findElements(By.name("ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$DdlSessionExp"));
driver.findElements(By.name("ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$DdlfailedLogin"));
```

Can any one help me on this. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I did not understand. Could you please explain with more details and code? The 'findElement' method comes in two flavors: one will return a unique element or throw an exception or a list with the elements or an empty list. If the code is generated dynamically,will need to add an extra configuration to wait the ajax data changes in the DOM tree.

Comment: The above fields are dropdowns, i need to verify whether they are displayed in Y screen when selected a checkbox in X screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifications should be done using xUnit-system and Asserts. E.g. JUnit or TestNG for Java. You can do the verification the following way with TestNG (for JUnit the order of arguments is slightly different):

```
Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElements(By.name("ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$DdlPwdExp")).size(), 1, 
    "Password field wasn't found"); 
Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElements(By.name("ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$DdlSessionExp")).size(), 1,
    "Some other field wasn't found"); 
Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElements(By.name("ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$DdlfailedLogin")).size(), 1, 
    "Whatever field wasn't found");
```

Answer (score 0):

First I have resolved my problem by using above answer from Khrol, and i have tried another method also, which resolved my problem completely.

```
int size = driver.findElements(By.name("ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$DdlPwdExp")).size();
if (size > 0)
{
System.out.println("No. of Days for Password Expiration field: is displayed");
}
else
{
System.out.println("No. of Days for Password Expiration field: is not displayed");
}
```